# How to display text or Popup in kivy while python sript is running

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hi everyone reading this topic.

That what i trying to do is: automaticly display text in Label after value is match in if statment.
Second option could be Popup insted Label.
Third way could be jump to different screen.

Please help me,
i don't really know how can i connect this with kivy without using any buttons.
Here are codes:

python:

```
from kivy.app import App
import random
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Main(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Numbers(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


    def process(self):

        num_list = ['four','three']
        number = random.choice(num_list)
        self.number.text = number
        print(number)
        while True:

            if number == 'null':
                pass
            elif number == 'three':
                pass
            elif number == 'four':
                self.root.ids.numb.text="four"
                print(' for example Here i need connect code with kivy to display on screen text as string or jump to another screen')
                break
            else:
                pass
kv = Builder.load_file('temp.kv')


class NumbersApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NumbersApp().run()
```

and kv file:

```
Main:
    Numbers:
<Numbers>:
    number:numb
    cols:1
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            id: numb
            text: 'Text display after getting \ninfo from script in while loop \nin process def'
            font_size: '15'
            hint_size: None, None
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.04, 'y': -0.4}
            color: 1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Add this under your elif statement ```self.root.ids.numb.text="four"```

Comment: It's still  not working, text on label stay the same. Some reason i don't get even printed string in console called 'number'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
self.root.ids.numb.text="four"
```

is incorrect because the `numb` `id` is in the `Numbers` object, but you are trying to access a `root` attribute of the `Numbers` object. Just change that line to:

```
self.ids.numb.text = "four"
```

which accesses the correct `ids`.

So here is a modified version of your `kv` that includes a `Button` to start `process()`

```
Main:
    Numbers:
<Numbers>:
    number:numb
    cols:1
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            id: numb
            text: 'Text display after getting \\ninfo from script in while loop \\nin process def'
            font_size: '15'
            hint_size: None, None
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.04, 'y': -0.4}
            color: 1,1,1,1
        Button:
            text: 'Start Process'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
            on_release: root.start_process()
```

And here is a modified version of your `Numbers` class that uses another `Thread` and `Clock.schedule_once()`:

```
class Numbers(Screen):
    def start_process(self):
        # run process() on another thread
        threading.Thread(target=self.process, daemon=True).start()

    def process(self):
        print('process')
        num_list = ['four','three']
        number = random.choice(num_list)
        print(number)
        while True:

            if number == 'null':
                pass
            elif number == 'three':
                pass
            elif number == 'four':
                print(' for example Here i need connect code with kivy to display on screen text as string or jump to another screen')
                Clock.schedule_once(self.set_text)  # set text on the main thread
                break
            else:
                pass

    def set_text(self, dt):
        self.ids.numb.text = "four"
```

Comment: It don't have now any error but only i get is output in console after condition is correct, but i don't get any update in kivy gui.

Comment: How are you starting the `process()` method?

Comment: That's is good point! I add button to start a function and all is working now. I appreciate the quick help, thank you.

Comment: when i use break function then text is updating in gui. The thing is after that process function break as well and i need press button again. Is any way to automate this process to stay in while loop? Basicly i would like to update Label by self every time is changing while running in while loop without break function.

Comment: If you run `process()` by pressing a `Button`, then you are running it on the main thread. The main thread is used by Kivy to update the GUI. So, as long as you are running something on the main thread, the GUI cannot update until that `process()` completes. I would suggest running `process()` in another thread, and use `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule a call to another method that does the `self.ids.numb.text = "four"`.

Comment: if you don't mind could you give me some example into this case ? I'm trying put it into my code that clock.schedule  or even use  Popup but without any progress...

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank You, all working as should so yea thank a lot!! , only quit() function instead turn off my entire app is onl;y going out of loop.